# Position of Range-Object in Excel

Tags: perl, excel, win32ole

I am trying to figure out how to get the position of a selected Range in an Excel(2007)-Worksheet. Is there something similar to `$self->{EXCEL}->ActiveCell->Row` for Cells (`self->{EXCEL}` being an Excel-Object)?

I tried `->Selection->Range`, `->ActiveSheet->Range`, and as a workaround `->Range->Row`, `->Range->Rows` both with an Excel- and a Worksheet-Object with no success.

The most fancy output being two Cell-Objects, one for the start-address, the other one end-address.

Thanks for any helpful hints!

=== Update ===

I now use successfully the command `$self->{EXCEL}->Selection->Address();` to retrieve the address of the selected range. By default I get the address in "A1"-format (`$E$1:$G$14`). Using `->Address("ToReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1")` however does not return the address in "R1C1"-format as I would have expected...

Faulty command? Ignorant Excel? Thanky again on any helpful hint!

Comment: In VBA: `Selection.Cells(1).Address()` and `Selection.Cells(Selection.Cells.Count).Address()` would give you the location of the start and end cell, assuming it's a contiguous regular range which is selected.

Comment: I made an edit to try to assist in your 2nd question. Why not create a new one though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `->Selection->Address`? I'm not sure on the format, but the address property of the selection (range object) will give you the address of the range for example. `$A$1:$B$7`. You would be able to parse the start and end by splitting the string on the colon.

To address your new questions... I'm not even sure if what you're using, but the third parameter of the address method is ReferenceStyle not ToReferenceStyle. So I would try either `->Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)` or `->Address(,,xlR1C1)`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, they are very helpful! `->Selection->Address` does the trick, as does the commands mentioned in @Tim 's comment.

Comment: Thanks again @Daniel, also for giving me hints on using stackoverflow :-) However, both commands return the address in A1 format as well.

Comment: This is a bit outdated, but instead of putting `xlR1C1`, you may want to try `-4150`